# Adding reviewer name automatically to the source files in subversion

Tags: svn, pre-commit-hook

I'm not an expert in `subversion`, and would appreciate very much for any hints on the following problem.

I want to add a review name automatically into a commented section in the header of the `Java` file (`.java` extension only). This can be done manually, but in case of large commits if would take ages to modify the header for hundreds of files. `svn pre-commit` hook, or other `svn` capability might be used here I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the documentation on subversion [keywords](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.4/svn.advanced.props.special.keywords.html). The `Author` keyword is the one that may solve your problem.

From the linked document:

> For example, say you have a document in which you have some section of
>   tabular data reflecting the document's Subversion keywords. Using the
>   original Subversion keyword substitution syntax, your file might look
>   something like:

```
 $Rev$:     Revision of last commit
 $Author$:  Author of last commit
 $Date$:    Date of last commit
```

> Now, that looks nice and tabular at the
>   start of things. But when you then commit that file (with keyword
>   substitution enabled, of course), you see:

```
 $Rev: 12 $:     Revision of last commit
 $Author: harry $:  Author of last commit
 $Date: 2006-03-15 02:33:03 -0500 (Wed, 15 Mar 2006) $:   Date of last commit
```

Comment: `reviewer` != `author`. Is there a way to specify the `reviewer` on commit manually?

Comment: author identifies the user performing the last commit. Who is the reviewer?

Comment: `reviewer` (or just a string) is a parameter that is specified on commit by the user who commits. Can a parameter be inserted using `keywords`?

Comment: @Leonid: What svn client are you using? `reviewer` is definitely not a standard parameter for subversion (see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re06.html)

Comment: The question is exactly about adding **not-standard user-specified** parameters. Do you know if there is any way to do it? I can think of a pre-commit hook that modified the code with externally specified variable.

Comment: It is not possible to define custom keywords, so you would have to implement this functionality on your own **pre-commit hook**. I'm still curious about the `reviewer`'s role...

Comment: The role of reviewer makes sense in a larger corporations where all code changes must be reviewed by someone else as a part of a formal procedure. Therefore, in some corporations reviewer must be specified in the file header.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't change content of transaction in pre-commit hook
2. You can (for the cost of overall commit-time **and** additional revision in history) modify needed files in post-commit hook, if you can write code, which perform this modification automatically (`Reviewer` value have to be stored as some path-property by hand before user's commit)